# How do I make a method that returns the result of the last-called method?

Tags: php, class, methods, attributes

I have a class and I have some methods meant for calculation I made such as divide(), multiply(), etc.

And I want to create a new method that we would call showResult() that will return the result of that last calculation method that has been called. For example:

```php
$foo = new MyTinyCalculator(30, 12);
echo $foo->add () . “\n”;
echo $foo->subtract () . “\n”;
echo $foo->multiply () . “\n”;
echo $foo->divide () . “\n”;
echo $foo->showResult () . “\n”;
/* displays
    42
    18
    360
    2.5
    2.5
*/
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```php
class MyTinyCalculator
{

    private $_a;
    private $_b;
    private $_result;


    function __construct(int $a, int $b)
    {
        $this->_a = $a;
        $this->_b = $b;
    }


    function getA()
    {
        return $this->_a;
    }
    function getB()
    {
        return $this->_b;
    }
    function setA($a)
    {
        $this->_a = $a;
    }
    function setB($b)
    {
        $this->_b = $b;
    }
    function getResult()
    {
        return $this->_result;
    }
    function setResult($result)
    {
        $this->_result = $result;
    }
    public function add()
    {

        return $this->_a + $this->_b . '<br>';
        $this->_result = $this->_a + $this->_b;
    }
    public function substract()
    {
        return $this->_a - $this->_b . '<br>';
        $this->_result = $this->_a - $this->_b;
    }

    public function divide()
    {
        return $this->_a / $this->_b . '<br>';
        $this->_result = $this->_a / $this->_b;
    }
    public function multiply()
    {
        return $this->_a * $this->_b . '<br>';
        $this->_result = $this->_a * $this->_b;
    }
    function showResult()
    {
        echo $this->_result;
    }
}
```

```php
$calculator = new MyTinyCalculator(30, 12);
echo $calculator->add();
echo $calculator->substract();
echo $calculator->multiply();
echo $calculator->divide();
echo $calculator->showResult();
```

It only displays:

```
42
18
360
2.5
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing the leading `_` from properties, see [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#43-properties-and-constants)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

In a function, when you call `return` the function stops there, so the line where you assign a value to `$this->_result` will not be called

This should work for you

```php
    public function add()
    {
        $this->_result = $this->_a + $this->_b;
        return $this->_result . '<br>';
    }
    public function substract()
    {
        $this->_result = $this->_a - $this->_b;
        return $this->_result . '<br>';
    }

    public function divide()
    {
        $this->_result = $this->_a / $this->_b;
        return $this->_result . '<br>';
    }
    public function multiply()
    {
        $this->_result = $this->_a * $this->_b;
        return $this->_result . '<br>';
    }
    function showResult()
    {
        echo $this->_result;
    }
```